# How to make listview items clickable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview that is connected to a datasource. When I view the project in a browser, the listview is populated with data from the Northwind database. I just have the CustomerID and ContactTitle columns displayed. I want to be able to click on the CustomerID and then display the rest of the information about that particular customer. I've searched and searched and searched and tried a ton of different things but I just can't figure out how to make the CustomerID clickable. I am using c# and ASP.NET. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a itemTemplate that contains various controls and bind the columns of your datasource to those controls. For the field in question you want to make sure you select a "clickable" control. like a link, button or even a div, and then create a handler for that click event. A good example of such a thing can be found in MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337898.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do your list items contain li's? Whatever tag you use, you would use the javascript onclick event on each li to initiate whatever action you require.

If you need to retrieve customer data you could [initiate a postback](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx) from your javascript to retrieve the data and display the customer details.